# JQuery timeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, timeout

I am trying to use jquery/javascript to do the following but am having trouble finding any information about how to get it done.

I want to create a function that when called, will wait for 2 seconds for a response from the user (a keypress for example). If a response is collected anytime within the 2 seconds, event A is executed while if there is no keypress withing 2 seconds, event B is executed.

```
function waitForInput
{
if(response within 2 second timeout?) event a executed
else if (timed out) event b executed
}
```

Comment: Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var timeOut;

$('#input').on('keyup', function () {
    if (timeOut) {
       clearTimeout(timeOut);
       $('#div').removeClass('a');  // corresponds to Event A
    }
    timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#div').addClass('a');  // corresponds to Event B
    },1000);
    console.log(timeOut)
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/tzcwc/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

use setTimeout to handle this:

```
setTimeout(2000, function decide () {
    if (keyPressed) 
    {
       //do A
    } else
    { 
      // do B
    }
}
```